# my api xml comments are not updating in swagger UI .NetFramework Not .netcore

Tags: asp.net, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle, .net-framework-version

Only some of the summary tags on my controller actions are showing up. And if I change the description in any of them it does not update in swagger UI it still displays the original first time I built comments and I have checked the xml file swagger is using all the updated comments are there but not displaying any help??

[image]

Comment: Can you create a minimal project reproducing your issue, and post the code here or a link to the project?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Because we are not using whole numbers for our api versioning we are using 1, 1.1, 1.2 etc. It was only able to grab v1 and not the others properly because of the namespaces being different controller.v1 matches the api of 1 it was able to get that but controller.v1._1 did not match 1.1 and there is a line for the of code in swagger for multiple api versioning it has ResolveVersionSupportByRouteConstraint. where that code is you need to add a .Replace to change the namespace of 1._1 to equal 1.1 so swagger can understand it.